# Adding characters before a link in anchor link

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add characters or URL before a link in each anchor link, for example i want to add `https://shorten.com/api/`:

```
<a class="destination" href="https://shorten.com/api/https://destinationlink.com">visit</a>
```

How can I do that, should I use javascript?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please add some more information. Maybe some code to help us understand the issue you are facing. It’s all dependant.

Comment: Have a look here. It could help you solve your issue with JQuery. http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/

Comment: Have you considered modifying your HTML and just putting your URL prefix there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` to select all the elements. Then loop through all of them with `forEach()` to prefix the *href* attribute value with the new value:

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.destination');
el.forEach(function(a){
  a.href += 'https://shorten.com/api/';
  console.log(a.href); // new href value
});
```

```html
<a class="destination" href="https://destinationlink.com">visit</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do this with javascript, no jQuery required.

```js
function prependApi() {
  var anchor = document.querySelector('.your-api-link');
  var newUrl = 'http://somenewurl.com/';
  var originalUrl = anchor.getAttribute('href');

  anchor.setAttribute('href', newUrl + originalUrl);
}

prependApi();
```

```html
<a class="your-api-link" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select target anchor using `querySelector()` and change `href` attribute of it using `href` property

```js
var anchor = document.querySelector(".destination");
anchor.href = "https://shorten.com/api/"+anchor.href;
```

```html
<a class="destination" href="https://destinationlink.com">visit</a>
```

Also you can use jQuery to do this work

```js
$(".destination").attr("href", function(i, href){
  return "https://shorten.com/api/"+href;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="destination" href="https://destinationlink.com">visit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some options to use css content with a psuedo element, but it is quite limited compared to javascript.

```css
.destination:before {
  content: attr(href);
  width: 9em;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<a class="destination" href="https://shorten.com/api/https://destinationlink.com">visit</a>
```